# Gradle: how to make JavaExec task use configuration classpath?

Tags: java, gradle, build-process

Here's the problem: I want to execute some java class with some dependencies from, say, runtime configuration. How can this be done?

```
task runJava(type: JavaExec, dependsOn:[classes]) {
        main = 'mypackage.MyClass'
        classpath = //what should I write here to provide classes from runtime configuration?
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will probably want to use the runtime classpath of your [Source sets](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N11B52) which includes the [compiled classes of your project as well as all the runtime dependencies](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet:runtimeClasspath).

```
task runJava(type: JavaExec, dependsOn:[classes]) {
    main = 'mypackage.MyClass'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

In case you want to the get the path of a specific configuration you can do something like this: `configurations.getByName('runtime').asPath` or shorter `configurations.runtime.asPath`.

Comment: worth bearing in mind that calling `asPath` will resolve the configuration so you may need to be careful you don't end up resolving the configuration unintentionally during the configuration phase

Comment: When using gradle in Android Studio there is no sourceSets.main - anyone have an idea what you'd have to use in Case of Android Studio's Gradle version? Only thing I found so far is android.sourceSets.main but it got no runtimeClasspath and I am not even sure it's the right thing.

Comment: I get Error:(38, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.
> Could not get unknown property 'sourceSets' for task ':runApp' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.