# Custom task with JavaExec and gradle 8

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have tried several ways of creating custom task with JavaExec. I use gradle 8.

```
tasks {
    val prepareDataset by creating(JavaExec::class) {
        dependsOn("build")

        // set the main class to be executed
        mainClass.set("com.analytic.training.TrainingAppKt")

        // set the arguments to pass to the main method (optional)
        args("--arg1=value1", "--arg2=value2")

        // set the classpath
        // classpath(configurations.getByName("runtimeClasspath"))
        // classpath(jvmRuntimeClasspath)

        // set the task description
        description = "Prepares the training dataset"
        group = "training"
    }
}
task<JavaExec>("prepareDataset2") {
    dependsOn("build")

    // set the main class to be executed
    mainClass.set("com.analytic.training.TrainingAppKt")

    // set the arguments to pass to the main method (optional)
    args("--arg1=value1", "--arg2=value2")

    // set the classpath
    // classpath(configurations.getByName("runtimeClasspath"))
    // classpath(jvmRuntimeClasspath)
    classpath = java.sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath

    // set the task description
    description = "Prepares the training dataset"
    group = "training"
}
```

Both does not work

```
Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates
[com.analytic.AnalyticApplicationKt, com.analytic.training.TrainingAppKt]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `classpath(configurations.runtimeClasspath)` ([from this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683613/4161471)). Configurations are linked to tasks, so Gradle should automatically detect what tasks to run in order to compute the value of `configurations.runtimeClasspath` - so there's no need for manual task dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It works after I change `dependsOn("build")` to `dependsOn("classes")`. I think it conflicts with spring boot.

```
task<JavaExec>("prepareDataset") {
    dependsOn("classes")

    // set the main class to be executed
    mainClass.set("com.analytic.training.TrainingAppKt")

    // set the arguments to pass to the main method (optional)
    args("--arg1=value1", "--arg2=value2")

    // set the classpath
    // classpath(configurations.getByName("runtimeClasspath"))
    // classpath(jvmRuntimeClasspath)
    classpath = java.sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath

    // set the task description
    description = "Prepares the training dataset"
    group = "training"
}
```